# Navigating to the method behind an event in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am working with some legacy code that uses a lot of events. Basically, every method is called throught an event. All those events have only one subscriber.

When reading some code that raises an event, how can I quickly navigate to the code of this one subscriber?

e.g I am reading trough some code:

```
event xy DoStuff_Event;
void foo()
{
    DoStuff_Event()
}
```

Now I want to know what code would be executed here.

So I click on `DoStuff_Event()`->"Find all references"

Then I search the references for the line `DoStuff_Event += DoStuff_ForReal()` 
(There is always only one such line in this codebase)

Then I click on `DoStuff_ForReal()`->"Go to definition"

Now I finally can read the code that will be executed when `DoStuff_Event()` is called. Usually this code will consist of several further event calls, which in turn call even more events, so I repeat the whole process.

Is there a faster way to jump from the line `DoStuff_Event()` to the method definition of `DoStuff_ForReal()`?

For my case, when there is always only one subscriber for each event, it seems like this search could be automated.

Comment: Weren't they using the Something / OnSomething convention?

Comment: That convention is used sometimes, but not consistently, and often there are slight differences in the names like "SomethingXY / OnFooSomething" or "SomethingHandler / OnHandleSomething" or "HandleSomethingEvent / OnSomething"

Comment: Have you tried "View call hierarchy" from right click on a member?

Comment: The call hirarchy, when clicking on `DoStuff_Event()`, only contains the following: "calls to 'Invoke' - Search found no results ; ; calls from 'Invoke' - 'Calls From' is not supported for delegate members"